# Scrapy request url comes from which url response

Tags: scrapy

For Scrapy, we could get the response.url, response.request.url, but how do we know the response.url, response.request.url is extracted from which parent url?

Thank you,
Ken

Comment: I use `response.request.headers.get('referer')` to get the parent url. But it is not always working, especially for the redirected urls

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Request.meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) to keep track of such information.

When you yield your request, include `response.url` in the meta:

```py
yield response.follow(link, …, meta={'source_url': response.url})
```

Then read it on your parsing method:

```py
source_url = response.meta['source_url']
```

That is the most straightforward way to do this, and you can use this method to keep track of original URLs even across different parsing methods, if you wish.

Otherwise, you might want to look into taking advantage of the [`redirect_urls` meta key](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-redirect_urls), which keeps track of redirect jumps.